# drupal 7 Displaying data from different content type in single row in views using relationships

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a Taxonomies like group , category hobbies, CV and i have a 3 content types.

1st content type is Company which has a field project code , then it has field called CV which is of type term reference to Taxonomies CV.

There is a field  called group and category which are both term reference of to taxonomy group and category

Similarly i have field called RM which is entity reference of type User and account manager which is also a entity reference of type user.

Another Content type called CXO which has fields name , number, and Hobbies which is a term reference to Taxonomy hobbies.
In This we have a field company which is entity reference of content type company created above so this person belongs to one among companies.

Last Content type is Coordinator which also has all same fields as CXO and it also has hobbies as term reference. Similarly as CXO we also have a field company which is  entity reference of content type company.

So i wanted to view all the fields together in one table.

Like Project code, company , CV , category , Group , RM , Name from CXO , Number from CXO , Hobby from CXO , Name from Coordinator , Number and Hobbies of Coordinator.

ALl these data i wanted to be come in a single row, like one project will have all these details.

Please help me with this, i think something i have to do with relationships, Can somebody help me with this.?

Answer (score 0):

In order to gain access to the fields of other content types you should add in the relationships area the appropriate entity reference field.
For example if you want to make available in a companies view all the CXOs you should add in relationships the referencing entity "A bridge to the Content entity that is referenced via field company" .
Due to many many relationships at your case you 'll end up with many duplicates so I 'd suggest to use the distinct setting under "query settings" or a "group by" in aggregation settings.